# 5. 1.1 Legal: Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

Tags: ios

We noticed that your app requires users to register with personal information to access non account-based features. Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app content and features that are not associated specifically to the user.

We are taking Email id on SignUp because all data is tracking in Backend behalf on Email id. What to do? Please anybody help me.

[image]

Comment: does your app has user account specific features?

Comment: Some Feature like menu screen Appears with Restaurant Product Item after select product user can place order.

Comment: login is required to enter in your app ? or you are just taking userdetails at a signup time and there is no login screen at all ? you should refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495145/rejected-app-17-2-apps-that-require-users-to-share-personal-information) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561238/app-rejected-on-17-2-clause-asking-for-email-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Apple does not know where you are using Email ID...So to solve this issue what you can do is you can send the otp to users Email Address to verify valid user and you can give the reason as  After the user order is confirmed you are going to send order confirmation mail and there Bill details in their Email id....Just mention all this Terms and condition in one screen what i have said above.I hope it helps..Thanks.

Comment: user Data is fetching by email id from backend and in forgot password password will be sent to email id.

Comment: Have you given Terms and conditions in your App?

Comment: can i see the signup screen of your App?

Comment: Is Signup Compulsary Jsut for Browsing the Application?

Comment: after this rejection i have gave the skip button in login and signup

Comment: Have you  Tried submitting you App after giving Skip Button?

Comment: I think by giving Skip Option the above issue is solved...May i no whats the other issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158844/discussion-between-vikas-rajput-and-neeraj-sonaro).

Comment: using api like this 192.230.66.71/XXXXXXXX/XX
apple rejecting app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246639/your-app-crashed-on-ipad-and-iphone-running-ios-11-1-connected-to-an-ipv6-networ?noredirect=1#comment81468887_47246639

Comment: please see my above Question